# HL7 to JSON conversion using JAVA

Tags: hapi, hl7-fhir

Do we have any mechanism to convert HL7 messages to json format in JAVA? I was going through HAPI FHIR library but could not find any such APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean HL7 v2.x with HL7 messages. hapi-fhir doesn't have the v2 -> FHIR functionality out of the box. You can implement this by yourself using hapi-fhir and [hapi-hl7v2](https://hapifhir.github.io/hapi-hl7v2/). For smaller implementations this can be done quite fast. 
There is also a commercial version of hapi-fhir called smile which brings this functionality out of the box: [smileCDR](https://smilecdr.com/)